# How can I record with multiple mics at once?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, audacity

I am starting a podcast with two other people and so far I have the mics connected to a mixer that runs to the mic port of my computer. I have set it to recognize the device as a mic, line in and stereo mix but each time it doesn't record audio in audacity. Instead I get a nasty constant white noise. I have checked many a forum and guide but nothing seems to help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your computers mic port cannot handle what you are looking for. Does the mixer have USB (or equivelant) out?

Answer (score 1):

Microphones need high "pre"-amplification, so they need to be directly connected to mic-inputs. If your mixer has those (usually XLR), you're good. The mixer out should be connected to a line in (as it does not need that much pre-amplification).

Also there are two general types of microphones: dynamic and condenser, with the 2nd type needing power, in the form of batteries or phantom power (provided by the mixer).

I suspect that you either provide no power but have mic's that need it or you have connected the mics to line inputs.